# Upgrading MacBookPro

Tags: macos, mac, performance, upgrade, macbook-pro

I'm using a Late 2011 13" MacBook Pro with an Intel i5 @ 2.4 GHz and 4 GB 1333 MHz ram. The computer has started to get older. I was going to upgrade the ram but since Mavericks come out, the ram problem just went away and now, it started to get slower and slower. So I was thinking of upgrading my ram to at least 8GB and my CPU. I have two question about that. As I have 1333Mhz rams installed by default, the motherboard should not support 1666Mhz rams. But can I use 1666 Mhz ones and if I can will it make any difference? Also is it possible to upgrade the CPU of my computer? If yes how can I find a CPU compatible with the other components?

Comment: A computer will use the slowest of the following: Maximum RAM controller speed and maximum RAM module speed (all modules are considered separately). Installing slower RAM is not a problem, neither is installing faster RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You can install RAM of 1600MHz and the computer will automatically downclock it to 1333MHz. If you want to go nuts on upgrading RAM, your computer supports up to 16GB. If you're interested in squeezing the most possible performance out of your RAM upgrade, you should try to get 1333MHz sticks. They will likely have better latency than any 1600MHz sticks you can find.

2) You are not able to upgrade the CPU of your MacBook.

Comment: This is partly wrong. According to [this page](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1270#link1), the maximum amount of supported memory is 8 GB.

Comment: Officially, Apple only supports 8GB of RAM. In practice, the logic board actually supports 16GB.

Answer (score 0):

High productivity gains more memory will not (although it certainly will increase). The best option is to increase the RAM and replacing the HDD to SSD. When choosing RAM note that Mac is very demanding, may refuse to work with some RAM manufacturers. I'm on an identical Mac, also changed the RAM installed Corsair Mac Memory 8GB (2 x 4GB) Dual Channel DDR3 SODIMM Memory Kit, works fine.I recommend SSD Samsung 840 PRO or 840 EVO. Sorry for my english, it's Google.